# Calculation of Ext

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be an abelian group.

I know that $Ext_\mathbb{Z}^1(\mathbb{Z}/p,A)=A/pA$.

Are there any similar formula about $Ext_\mathbb{Z}^1(A,\mathbb{Z}/p)$?

I know that $Ext_R^n(A,B)\neq Ext_R^n(B,A)$ generally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need an *injective* resolution for $\mathbb Z/p$ in the second variable. An Abelian group is injective if and only if it is *divisible*.

So, the first step will be to embed $\mathbb Z/p$ into a divisible Abelian group. For this, we can use the [Prüfer $p$-group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasicyclic_group) $\mathbb Z(p^\infty)$.

The cokernel of this embedding is again the Prüfer $p$-group, so that we get the injective resolution $\mathbb Z(p^\infty)\to\mathbb Z(p^\infty)$ given by multiplication with $p$.

Hence we get
$$
Ext_\mathbb{Z}^1(A,\mathbb{Z}/p)=\frac{Hom_\mathbb{Z}(A,\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty))}{p\cdot Hom_\mathbb{Z}(A,\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty))}.
$$

I don't think that it is easy to understand homomorphisms *into* $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ because it is a *direct/injective* limit. (Edit: But please read Matt E's comment below.)

Comment: Aha, then, if $A$ is torsion abelian group, then $Ext_\mathbb{Z}^1(A,\mathbb{Z}/p)$ is trivial since $Hom_\mathbb{Z}(A,\mathbb{Z})=0$. Right? But, I remember that $Ext_\mathbb{Z}^1(\mathbb{Z}/p,\mathbb{Z}/p)=\mathbb{Z}/p$. Isn't it?

Comment: Right, that follows from the observation is your question. Let met think for a moment.

Comment: Now, your answer seems to be perfect. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Thanks, that's nice to hear.

Comment: Well, Rasmus fixed his reply, while I was typing, so I will remove my incomplete mumblings.

Comment: Dear Rasmus, Note that Homs into $\mathbb Z(p^{\infty})$ are a version of the Pontrjagin dual of $A$, and so not so strange or necessarily difficult to compute (at least for e.g. finitely generated $A$).  (See my answer for a little more explanation.) Best wishes,

Answer (score 6):

Form the injective resolution $$0 \to \dfrac{1}{p}\mathbb Z/\mathbb Z \to
\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z \buildrel \cdot p \over \to \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z \to 0.$$
Applying $\mathrm{Hom}(A,\text{--})$ to this, we find that 
$$\mathrm{Ext}^1(A, \mathbb Z/p) = 
\mathrm{Ext}^1(A,\dfrac{1}{p}\mathbb Z/\mathbb Z)
= {\mathrm Hom}(A,\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)/p.$$

Note that $\mathrm{Hom}(A,\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)$ is (speaking somewhat informally; see my comment addressed to Rasmus below) a version of the
Pontrajagin dual of $A$.  (In particular, if $A$ is torsion, then it
is precisely the Pontrjagin dual.)  In fact, we could replace $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$
by the circle group $S^1$ in the above injective resolution, and then 
we would find that
$$\mathrm{Ext}^1(A,\mathbb Z/p) = \hat{A}/p\hat{A},$$
where $\hat{A} = \mathrm{Hom}(A,S^1)$ *is* the Pontrjagin dual of the abelian group $A$ (with its discrete topology).

[Note: I began writing this answer some hours ago, but then got distracted.
It is essentially the same as that of Rasmus, although, rather than using
either $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ or $S^1$, he uses $\mathbb Z(p^{\infty})$, which is
the $p$-power torsion part of $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$.  (If you like, you can write it as $\mathbb Q_p/\mathbb Z_p$.)  These different descriptions reflect the flexibility available in choosing an injective resolution of $\mathbb Z/p$.]

Comment: The maximally useful is the one using $S^1$, though, because the result looks like it might have a meaning :)

Comment: What does "*a* version of the Pontrjagin dual" mean?

Comment: @Rasmus: Dear Rasmus, Strictly speaking, Pontrjagin duality means Homs into the circle group $S^1$.  But for a torsion group this is the same as Homs into $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z_p$, and it is sometimes useful (at least for me) to think of taking Homs into $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$, or even $\mathbb Q_p/\mathbb Z_p$ if one is primarily focussed on $p$-power torsion modules, as a kind of variant of Pontrjagin duality.   I didn't mean more anything more than that.  Regards,

Comment: Dear Matt, thank you for the explanation. Best,

Comment: @Rasmus: Dear Rasmus, You're welcome.  Also, you probably noticed a minor typo in my previous comment:  $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z_p$ should read $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$.  Regards,

Answer (score 3):

I would just add that $\operatorname{Ext}(A,G)$ is fully computable when $A$ and $G$ are finitely generated abelian groups.

You can find the proofs in any decent book on homological algebra:

1) If $A$ is free abelian, then $\operatorname{Ext}(A,G)=0$

2) If $G$ is [divisible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group) $\operatorname{Ext}(A,G)=0$

3) $\operatorname{Ext}(A,\prod G_j)=\prod \operatorname{Ext}(A,G_j)$

4) $\operatorname{Ext}(\sum A_j,G)=\prod \operatorname{Ext}(A_j,G)$

5) $\operatorname{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z},G)=G/mG$ (as noted)